# In the following code(C language), on each iteration, 1 << n calculated again and again?

Tags: for-loop, bit-shift

**In the following code(C language), on each iteration, 1 << n calculated again and again** ??
and the overhead could be **significant** in competitive programming for the
larger inputs??

```
#define for(i,n) for(int i=0;i<(n);++i)
for(i,1<<n){
    ...
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this? It looks like C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but this is not a programming issue, but a compiler optimisation issue.

In C , most of the compiler will be able to 'see' that n his modified or not inside the loop, and modify the condition.

So as a programmer, don't worry about this unless you have very specific constraint and conditions

So if you do this:

```
 int n=10;
 for(i=0;i<(1<<n);i++){
    n=func(i)
 }
```

1 < < n will be recomputed at each iteration, while in this case:

```
 int n=10;
 for(i=0;i<(1<<n);i++){
    println(i)
 }
```

It's higly probable that 1 < < n will be computed only once